# How to get index of the currently focused item in android gridview. <EOM>

Tags: android, gridview, grid, focus

Is there any API to track the index of a GridView in Android?

Comment: Did you tried anything? <EOM>

Comment: Handle the `OnTouchListener` or `OnItemClickListener` events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know the last focused image in previous Gridview in Android apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391395/how-to-know-the-last-focused-image-in-previous-gridview-in-android-apps)

Comment: you will get position of the particular item on onitemClickListener of the gridView

Comment: @ Shah : Tried with getCheckedItemPosition(), findFocus(), etc. But, that is of no use..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you set an `OnItemClickListener` to your GridView?

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(
    new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(), 
                String.format("Clicked on position #%s (id = %s)", position, id), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
        }   
    }
);
```

Comment: as a side note, IMO `String.format(...)` looks much better then multiple concatenations.

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov Valid point - I updated my answer accordingly. :)